# 'jQuery' undefined when using bundling in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

This is my 1st time using mvc bundles & I'm having an issue with my jquery bundle.  If I reference my jquery with the following, everything's fine:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

However, if I use this, I get the good ole "**'jQuery' is undefined**" error:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/plugins/jquery/js")
```

Here's my full code:
My View:

```
<!-- /// Jquery plugins ////////  -->
 @Scripts.Render(~/bundles/base/jquery/js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/plugins/jquery/js")

<!-- /// Animations ////////  -->
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/animations/js")

<!-- /// Plugins ////////  -->
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/plugins/js")

<!-- /// gMap ////////  -->
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/gmap/js")

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/twitter/js")

<!-- /// Custom JS ////////  -->
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/custom/js")

@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my BundleConfig:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/base/jquery/js").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/plugins/jquery/js").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/viewport/jquery.viewport.js",
                    "~/Scripts/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js",
                    "~/Scripts/simpleplaceholder/jquery.simpleplaceholder.js",
                    "~/Scripts/fitvids/jquery.fitvids.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/animations/js").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/animations/animate.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/plugins/js").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/superfish/hoverIntent.js",
                    "~/Scripts/superfish/superfish.js",
                    "~/Scripts/revolutionslider/js/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/revolutionslider/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts//magnificpopup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/isotope/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/parallax/jquery.parallax.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/easypiechart/jquery.easypiechart.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/itplayer/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.js",
                    "~/Scripts/easytabs/jquery.easytabs.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/waypoints/waypoints.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jqueryvalidate/jquery.validate.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jqueryform/jquery.form.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/gmap/js").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/gmap/jquery.gmap.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/twitter/js").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/twitter/twitterfetcher.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/custom/js").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/plugins.js",
                    "~/Scripts/scripts.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/base.css",
                    //"~/Content/boxed.css",
                    "~/Content/elements.css",
                    "~/Content/grid.css",
                    "~/Content/layout.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/fontawesome/css").Include("~/Content/fontawesome/font-awesome.min.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/iconfont/css").Include("~/Content/icon-font-custom.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/skins/css").Include("~/Content/skins/default.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/plugins/css").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/revolutionslider/css/settings.css",
                    "~/Scripts/revolutionslider/css/custom.css",
                    "~/Scripts/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css",
                    "~/Scripts/magnificpopup/magnific-popup.css",
                    "~/Scripts/animations/animate.min.css",
                    "~/Scripts/itplayer/css/YTPlayer.css"));
    }
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: I experienced this issue when I ran the bundling on localhost.  The issue was resolved after I changed including `.min.js` files to regular `.js` files in bundles.  If your render statements and paths are correct and still getting the same issue, perhaps give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/plugins/jquery/js").Include(
                "~/Scripts/viewport/jquery.viewport.js",
                "~/Scripts/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js",
                "~/Scripts/simpleplaceholder/jquery.simpleplaceholder.js",
                "~/Scripts/fitvids/jquery.fitvids.js"));
```

To

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/plugins/jquery/js").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/viewport/jquery.viewport.js",
                    "~/Scripts/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js",
                    "~/Scripts/simpleplaceholder/jquery.simpleplaceholder.js",
                "~/Scripts/fitvids/jquery.fitvids.js"));
```

Or...
Add

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/base/jquery/js")
```

Right above

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/plugins/jquery/js")
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you will not be referencing the jquery

lack this line in your code

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/base/jquery/js")
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized my problem.  Bundles seem to ignore .min script files.  [I followed the example from here and it seemed to have worked](https://stack247.wordpress.com/2014/04/18/asp-net-mvc-4-bundles-ignore-list/)